# How to get only the first document of multiple categories from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "driverId": 1234,
  "category": "SIMPLE",
  "location": {
    "lat": -40,
    "lon": 10        
  }
}
```

I have 3 different categories in this index, and I would like to perform the following query:

*Give me the closest drivers to this specific lat/lon combination, but give me only the first one for each category that I have*

Is it possible to do this with `ElasticSearch`? I imagine this is a stretch, and I can easily replace it with a `geo_distance` query and some manual filtering of the results, but if I could get it directly from the storage it'd be great.

Comment: Yes you'll probably have to do 3 geo_distance queries with sort and size =1 and combine them on the client side

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
{
  "_source": true, 
  "query":{
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort" : {
    "_script" : {
      "type" : "number",
      "script" : {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "(20 - doc['lat'].value) * (20 - doc['lat'].value) + (50 - doc['lon'].value) * (50 - doc['lon'].value)"
      },
      "order" : "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

This will sort your records ascending by the square of the distance (which will give the same sorting as the regular distance) from the location you give in the script (in this case {20;50}). But I think you will have to run it for each category. You can limit the result size for the search, but not for part of the search. So you will need to change the query for that to filter for one category.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html